# Inline citation for source refrenced a second time

Tags: citation

I'm using [IEEE citation style](http://www.ijssst.info/info/IEEE-Citation-StyleGuide.pdf). If information is cited from one source, then another, then again from the first how does the inline citation work?

Take the following made up example:

> Dogs make good pets[ 1 ]. Scientific studies show that dog owners get
>   more exercise[ 2  ]. As long as dogs receive walks on a regular basis
>   they will be well behaved[ 1 ].

Then would the works cited look like the following?

[ 1 ] J. Doe. *Benefits of Dogs*
[ 2 ] A. Jim. *Healthy Habits*

or would I have to include a [ 3 ] inline citation and add another entry to the works cited that would be identical to [ 1 ]?

Comment: Referencing questions are not on-topic and should be asked on the Writers site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about referencing styles. Style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S.Vidyaraman, a post-graduate student at the University of Kansas, has what appears to be a [better guide to IEEE citation](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/%7Ekrsna/citing.htm) than the one you are asking about. It's apparently originally published by Monash University.

> #### Citing - IEEE style citation
>
> The IEEE citation style is now widely used in Electrical, electronic and computing publications. Using this system, references are numbered in the order in which they are first cited in the text. If the same reference is cited later int he text, the same number is given. For example
>
> "The theory was first put forward in 1987 [1]"
>
> "Scholtz [2] has argued that......."
>
> "Several recent studies [3, 4, 15, 16] have suggested that..."

On the [Monash University website](http://guides.lib.monash.edu/content.php?pid=346637&sid=2835487), they add

> If you need to cite the same source more than once:
>
> Direct the reader to specific pages numbers  where necessary, for example, a quote, or specific sections of the reference you wish to highlight such as tables, figures, algorithms:
>
> ...see [12, Example 1].

So: yes, you use the same number more than once, and add explicit data on the location within the reference if necessary.

Comment: Respect. But I've never heard of a Users Guide to a Style Guide.